# Selenium Webdriver using Java - sendkeys with double slash

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm using Selenium WebDriver with Java. I'm trying to enter the text 'test' followed by 2 backslashes into a text field.

When I tried the following code -

driver.findElement(By.id("txtEditExcludeRegPath")).sendKeys("test\");

Only test\ is entered into the textbox. The remaining backslash is left out.

Can someone help me solve this problem.

Please note - Even in this post, I'm unable to view 2 consecutive slashes after 'test'. Only 1 \ gets posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the code like this (**Assuming you want the output as 'test\\'**):

```
driver.findElement(By.id("txtEditExcludeRegPath")).sendKeys("test\\\\");
```

**NOTE:** Normally backslashes are used to escape the character after it, hence if you want to escape two backslashes you will have to add two backslashes to it.