# JavascriptExecutor is not entering backslash(\) in textbox

Tags: javascript, java, selenium-webdriver, automation

JavascriptExecutor is not entering backslash() in textbox.  Can you please help me on this ?

(Normal Selenium sendKeys method is not working)

- Selenium WebDriver 3.14
- Internet Explorer 11

  > JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
  > jse.executeScript("arguments[0].value='\cest';", element);

Answer (score 0):

The backslash is used to scape characters as `\n \r \t`...

Maybe you want to use `'\\cest'` to output `\cest`.

Trying:

```
console.log('\cest')
console.log('\\cest')
```

You will notice the difference.

Hope this fixes your problem

Comment: I have tried above option but it is entering all text except backslash.  Any other solutions ?

Comment: In this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27294946/selenium-webdriver-using-java-sendkeys-with-double-slash?rq=1 are able to send text to elements. Maybe is useful to your case

Comment: JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver; jse.executeScript("arguments[0].value='\\\\cest';", element);       - Code is working